# SHOW STATUS LIKE in Sphinx SE

Tags: sphinx

After executing that query

```
select count(*) from tablename WHERE query=';';
```

that query will return count as 20.
But that table having totally 771498 records. while execute on SHOW STATUS LIKE 'sphinx_%';

it has return like this

```
+--------------------+--------+
| Variable_name      | Value  |
+--------------------+--------+
| sphinx_error       | 5732   |
| sphinx_time        | 837    |
| sphinx_total       | 1000   |
| sphinx_total_found | 771498 |
| sphinx_word_count  | 0      |
| sphinx_words       |        |
+--------------------+--------+
```

Here i have doubt .

- what is sphinx_error?
- what is sphinx_time?
- what is sphinx_total?
- what is sphinx_total_found?
- what is sphinx_word_count?
- what is sphinx_words?

It will be very helpful for me. Advance thanks

Answer (score 1):

firstly sphinxse is not a real mysql table. Its a fake table. It accepts a query, then sphinxse forwards it to a running instance in the background, and returns the results to produce a 'table' to mysql.

So count(*) wont work. It simply runs the query and counts the rows. There are only 20 rows, unless you ask for more.

- sphinx_error? - indicates an error - maybe SHOW WARNINGS would get the text.
- sphinx_time? - how long in milisecons the query took
- sphinx_total? - how many records you can actully retrieve (subject to max_matches)
- sphinx_total_found? - how many records actully match
- sphinx_word_count? - the number of words in your query
- sphinx_words? - how many docs/hits match each of the words - because you have no query, its empty.

Comment: thanks. Sphinx_error has return Value as 5732 for single following  query . select count(*) from tablename WHERE query=';'; SHOW STATUS LIKE 'sphinx_%'; Please confirm , It has returned , which are the errors / warnings comes to server on today.